# generating armstrong number to nth number in c not working

Tags: c, math

I am trying to generate armstrong number to nth number.So,I have written a code for that,but it is not working.Everytime I input a number like 999 or 10000,it return only 0....can anyone please help me to find out what's wrong with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double remainder,n=0;
    int number,sum = 0,q,x,count;

    printf("Enter an integer upto which you want to find armstrong numbers:");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("\nFollowing armstrong numbers are found from 1 to %d\n",number);

    for( count = 1 ; count <= number ; count++ )
    {
        q = count;
        x = count;
        for(;x != 0;)
         {
          x =x / 10;
          n = n + 1;
         }
        while(q != 0)
        {
           remainder = q % 10;
           sum = sum +(pow(remainder,n));
           q = q / 10;
        }
        if ( count == sum ){
        printf("%d\n", count);
        }
        sum = 0;
        }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize `n` to zero inside the loop for `count`. And take care of proper rounding of the result of `pow` by for example adding `0.5` to it.

Comment: I did that,now it is working and returning armstrong number to nth digit,but it is not returning 153 as an armstrong number.Why??

Comment: Weird. I do get 153. You are using `pow`, so there may be some rounding errors when truncating its result to `int`. Try adding `0.5` to the result of `pow`.

Comment: @Asiful Nobel Rather than adding 0.5, a uniform approach is to use `round()` as in `sum = sum + round(pow(remainder,n));`